# Using pytest to test a function that uses request library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pytest

I have a python function that calls out to an API using the request function. I want to test a 200 path, and then test a 500 error. I can't seem to figure out how to do it when looking at the requests-mock documentation.

Here is what I want to test.

```
def get_sku_data(sku: str):
    """
    Retrieve a single product from api
    """
    uri = app.config["SKU_URI"]
    url = f"{uri}/{sku}"
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "accept": "application/json",
    }
    try:
        retry_times = 3
        response = retry_session(retries=retry_times).get(url, headers=headers)
        return response.json()
    except ConnectionError as ex:
        raise Exception(f"Could not connect to sku api at {uri}. {ex}.")
    except requests.exceptions.RetryError:
        raise Exception(f"Attempted to connect to {uri} {retry_times} times.")

def retry_session(
    retries, backoff_factor=0.3, status_forcelist=(500, 502, 503, 504)
) -> requests.Session:
    """
    Performs a retry
    """
    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount("http://", adapter)
    session.mount("https://", adapter)
    return session
```

Here is my test stub that I'm trying to get going

```
# These test use pytest https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

# Note: client is a pytest fixture that is dependency injected from src/tests/conftest.py

import json
import pytest
from src.app import create_app
import requests
import requests_mock


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    return app


def test():
    session = requests.Session()
    adapter = requests_mock.Adapter()
    session.mount("mock", adapter)
    adapter.register_uri("GET", "mock://12", text="data")
    resp = session.get("mock://12")
    assert resp.status_code == 200
    assert resp.text == "data"
```

I'm a bit new to python testing, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Follow this : - https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html and then migrate to Fault Handler Section

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what I'm looking for. I read through it but really this is for mocking up requests and calling a method that uses it.

Comment: It's not quite clear what your test is testing. For `requests_mock` usage, check out the `pytest` example [in its docs](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytest.html).

Comment: That is currently what I have, but I don't understand what it is testing? The value gets provided as a return and then its called. Is it hitting endpoint logic?

Answer (score 0):

My perception of how it worked was wrong.
I register the URI I'm testing against and instead of calling session.get, I actually call the function under test.